# Can someone please explain how this function works?

Tags: javascript, function

```
function shuffle(o) {
    for(var j, x, i = o.length; i; j = parseInt(Math.random() * i), x = o[--i], o[i] = 
    o[j], o[j] = x);
    return o;
};
```

Not quite sure what the last part is doing

Comment: The last part returns an array (as the function reorders its elements in-place).

Comment: Looks like some minified code, or someone being "clever". Better to get the original code or ask the author. By the way "last part" is vague. I mean, the semi-colon (the last character of the code) is actually unnecessary, but tells the compiler the statement that precedes it is complete. As far as the `for` expression, [MDN has good documentation on that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#using_for_without_a_statement).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like someone taking up the challenge of *"I can do this in one line"*, which is a very neat and fun challenge, but has no place in real world code - your coworkers will hate you. So let's expand it into something readable:

```
function shuffle(o) {
    // iterate over the entire input array "o"
    for(var i = o.length - 1; i; i--) {
      // get the "current" item and save it in variable "x"
      var x = o[i];
      // generate a random number within the bounds of the array
      var j = parseInt(Math.random() * (i + 1));

      // The next two lines essentially swap item[i] and item[j]
      // set the "current" item to a randomly picked item
      o[i] = o[j];
      // put the "current" item in the random position
      o[j] = x;
    }

    return o;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function shuffle(inputArray) {
    let i = inputArray.length;

    while (i) {
        const j = parseInt(Math.random() * i); // generate random integer smaller than i (Math.random() generates random number between 0 and 1)
        i = i-1; 
        // swap elements on position i and j
        const element = inputArray[i];
        inputArray[i] = inputArray[j]
        inputArray[j] = x;
    }

    return inputArray;
};
```

Comment: for a new programmer, this conversion from a `for` to a `while` offers little help - try it with the original loop :)